# date: invalid date -d for string in another time zone

Tags: shell, date

Server set to Eastern timezone. Some of my tasks are relative to this timezone and some are relative to the Australia/Adelaide timezone.

```
$ DATE=`date`
$ echo $DATE
Mon Mon Jun 4 15:15:47 EDT 2018
$ DATE_Adelaide=`TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE"`
$ echo $DATE_Adelaide
Tue Jun 5 04:45:47 ACST 2018
$ dayName=$(date -d "${DATE_Adelaide}" +%a)
date: invalid date `Tue Jun 5 04:45:47 ACST 2018'
```

Comment: What do you want as the output? The local weekday corresponding to that (nonlocal) time, or...? Would it be easier to just use UTC times everywhere, or a numerical timezone instead of the abbreviations?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `date`... It doesn't like the timezone abbreviation `ACST`: if you run it with `--debug` e.g. `date --debug -d 'Tue Jun 5 04:45:47 ACST 2018'` it prints `date: error: unknown word 'ACST'`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU date, use the ISO8601 datetime format as the common transport format:

```
$ date_local=$(date --iso-8601=seconds)
$ echo "$date_local"
2018-06-04T17:01:45-04:00

$ date_adelaide=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$date_local" --iso-8601=seconds)
$ echo "$date_adelaide"
2018-06-05T06:31:45+09:30

$ day_name_local=$(date -d "$date_adelaide" +%a)
$ echo $day_name_local
Mon

$ day_name_adelaide=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$date_adelaide" +%a)
$ echo $day_name_adelaide
Tue
```

Comment: How do I know if I have a GNU date situation? If not GNU, then what? Mine fails on $ echo "$date_adelaide" -> date: invalid date `2018-06-04T19:34:04-0400'

Comment: $ date_local=$(date --iso-8601=seconds)
$ echo $date_local
2018-06-04T19:34:04-0400
$ date_adelaide=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$date_local" --iso-8601=seconds)
date: invalid date `2018-06-04T19:34:04-0400'

Comment: What OS are you  running?

Comment: $ uname -a
Linux d1mipvmmrs002 3.0.101-108.38-default #1 SMP Mon Apr 16 12:16:19 UTC 2018 (3dac46e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="11.4"
VERSION_ID="11.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:11:4"

Comment: How about `env | grep ^LC` ?

Comment: $ env | grep ^LC returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

On my system when I converted the date into the Australia/Adelaide timezone, and then tried to use that converted date in a subsequent "date" command, something in my system prevents the correct interpretation of ACST in the string. My solution was to output formatted portions of the date as it was being converted into the desired timezone.
DATE=$(date)
$ echo $DATE
Tue Jun 5 14:13:03 EDT 2018
$ TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE"
Wed Jun  6 03:43:03 ACST 2018
$    dayName=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE" +%a)
$ dayofmonth=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE" +%d)
$  dayofweek=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE" +%w)
$       hour=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE" +%H)
$    minutes=$(TZ=Australia/Adelaide date -d "$DATE" +%M)
echo $dayName $dayofmonth $dayofweek $hour $minutes
Wed 06 3 03 43